# Unir arquivos csv em um só

Tags: r

Tenho vários arquivos csv de dados que tem uma coluna em comum nomeada "Data". Se eu ler dois arquivos desse diretório a leitura é feita de maneira correta:

```
> P1<-read.csv("02650019.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
> P2<-read.csv("02650032.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")

> head(P1)

  Data       X2650019
1 1986-06-01        0
2 1986-06-02        0
3 1986-06-03        0
4 1986-06-04        0
5 1986-06-05        0
6 1986-06-06        0

> head(P2)

        Data X2650032
1 2000-04-01       NA
2 2000-04-02       NA
3 2000-04-03       NA
4 2000-04-04       NA
5 2000-04-05       NA
6 2000-04-06       NA
```

Mas quando eu vou fazer um Merge deles pela Data, o resultado aparece como se tivesse duas linhas de cada dados e não aparece na ordem temporal:

```
> merge1 <- merge(P1, P2, by = c("Data"), all = T)
> head(merge1)

        Data X2650019 X2650032
1 1976-07-01       NA       NA
2 1976-07-01       NA       NA
3 1976-07-02       NA       NA
4 1976-07-02       NA       NA
5 1976-07-03       NA       NA
6 1976-07-03       NA       NA
```

Não sei o que está acontecendo.

Na verdade eu queria fazer um Merge de todos os arquivos csv que eu tenho no meu diretório e não consigo pensar em um código para isso.

Comment: Não seria algo relacionado com o nome da coluna?

Comment: Por favor, transcreva o resultado dos comandos `dput(head(P1))` e `dput(head(P2))` para entendermos melhor como os dados estão estruturados. Outra coisa: essa data 197-07-01 aparece em P1 ou em P2?

Answer (score 5):

Não tenho seus arquivos aqui para testar, mas eu faria algo assim:

```
setwd("C://...") # caminho par ao seu diretório
arquivos <- list.files(path = "C://..", pattern = "*.csv") # caminho para o diretório e extensao deles

bases <- lapply(arquivos, function(x){
  b <- read.csv(x, header = TRUE, sep = ";")
  names(b) <- c("data", "x")
  b
})
library(dplyr)
rbind_all(bases)
```

A idéia é mais ou menos essa:

- coloco o diretório de trabalho como o diretório dos arquivos
- leio o nome de todos arquivos do diretório, com extensão csv
- leio todos os arquivos para o R e coloco todos os nomes no mesmo padrão
- empilho todos

Não sei se é exatamente isso que você quer.

Comment: off-topic: interessante saber que temos closures no R

Comment: Excelente reposta. Pela pergunta tb entendi que rbind() era o que estava sendo pedido