# Como juntar arquivos BibTex no R

Tags: r, bibtex

Como posso juntar vários arquivos de extensão `.bib` num só arquivo no R?

Estou aprendendo a usar o pacote Bibliometrix, e preciso juntar 99 arquivos `.bib` para um único arquivo.

Obrigado, pessoal.

Comment: Provavelmente vc só vai precisar adaptar esse código. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/48821/6036 O arquivo .bib é tipo um txt mesmo

Comment: Daniel, inicialmente muito obrigado pelo comentário. Fiz o que vc sugeriu e apareceu a seguinte mensagem:
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names 
5 stop("more columns than column names") 
4 read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, 
    dec = dec, fill = fill, comment.char = comment.char, ...) 
3 read.delim(x, header = TRUE, sep = ",", dec = ".") 
2 FUN(X[[i]], ...) 
1 lapply(em, function(x) read.delim(x, header = TRUE, sep = ",", 
    dec = ".")) 

Você sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Sou novo em programação e novo na utilização deste site. Me perdoe pela resposta um tanto bagunçada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução para o seu problema é ainda mais simples do que o código que o Daniel Falbel sugeriu. Você nem precisa do pacote `bibliometrix` porque ele mesmo lê os arquivos como texto. O que você precisa é apenas ler os arquivos, juntar em um objeto só e escrever novamente. Por exemplo:

```
files <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/Eu/MeusBibs", pattern = "\\.bib")
bibdata <- lapply(files, readLines)
write(unlist(bibdata), file = "big.bib")
```

Seu novo arquivo estará no diretório de trabalho do R.

Comment: Molx, muito obrigado!