# Com unir varios arquivos txt em um só

Tags: r

Eu tenho 60 arquivos txt todos com o mesmo numero de colunas. Os arquivos nao tem cabecalho (nome das colunas).

Como posso fazer para juntar todos num arquivo só um abaixo do outro no R.

Comment: Você vai conseguir fazer adaptando um pouco o que está aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/48821/6036

Comment: Também pode usar esse pacote do @Athospd https://github.com/Athospd/forkliftr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O código abaixo deve ser adaptado às tuas necessidades específicas, mas ele deve dar um bom ponto de partida. **Atenção:** o R deve estar configurado para o diretório em que os arquivos .txt estão localizados:

```
lista    <- list.files(pattern="txt")
arquivos <- lapply(lista, function(x) read.table(x, header=FALSE, sep=" ")) 
dados    <- do.call("rbind", arquivos)
```

Vamos quebrar ele em partes:

- `list.files` retorna todos os arquivos do diretório de acordo com um padrão. No caso, todos que tenham txt no título
- `lapply` aplica a função `read.table` para cada nome de arquivo presente em `lista`, considerando que os arquivos não possuem cabeçalho e que o separador de colunas é um espaço em branco. No teu caso, pode ser que este separador seja uma vírgula, um ponto e vírgula ou marcas de tabulação. Ajuste o código de acordo com as tuas necessidades.
- `do.call` aplica a função `rbind`, responsável por juntar data frames de acordo um em baixo do outro, nos dados que foram armazenados em `arquivos`